# Input image with circular FOV into CNN

Tags: conv-neural-network

I am working on a project that I need to train a CNN with Computer Tomography (CT) images, which has a circular Field Of View (FOV). All voxels outside the FOV is meaningless.

To my knowledge, people would usually only feed image with rectangular dimension into CNN model. For similar issues with circular image shape, they usually just crop part of the image to form a rectangular dimension during image-preprocessing. By this method, some part of the image is unavoidably cropped out from the training. Is there any way I can feed image with circular FOV into the model without cropping out any feature from the image? I can't really find similar topics for this concern on the internet so I ask here. Thank you.